# Under which circumstances should I wire together 2 different development boards' ground pins?

Tags: microcontroller, spi, ground

I have 2 stm32 nucleo boards. In one of them I configure a master SPI to send 10 bytes every 2 seconds, and the other has an SPI slave reading 10 bytes all the time. This 2 boards are connected to my laptop over USB.

I had a problem: the SPI slave was receiving the data shifted by one position. In the end, by chance, I tried to wire together both boards' ground pins and now it works.

I understand that both master and slave must have a common ground to understand each other, but having that both boards are connected to my laptop over USB, don't they already share the same ground (the one that comes from the USB port)?

Should 2 boards' GND pins always be wired? Can wire the GND pins, or not wire them, damage the boards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ground connection is the return path for the current. This is also true for signal lines - they may be high impedance, but the trace capacitance has still to be charged up for each amplitude change. And the capacitive current has to return via ground.

Now, when the only ground connection is via the USB cables, you have an insanly large ground loop, meaning there is a lot of inductance in the ground connection between the two devices. This makes fast signal changes like in an SPI connection very unreliable.

To directly answer your question: Whenever high speed signals are involved the ground connection should be as direct as possible to get good signal integrity.